# Any experience with Radiant Barriers?

Tags: radiant-barrier

I'm going to be putting up a ceiling on my back porch, which is glassed in.  The heat can be unbearable, so I thought I'd investigate insulation.  I keep coming up with recommendations for metallic/reflective radiant barriers.  They seem logical, I have an air gap between the joists, and the weight isn't going to strain my porch.   (Probably nothing is, but at my house, something always goes wrong.)

The porch roof is just over the bottom of the roof joists, which simply has insulation stuff in the open attic to block cold.  If the roof is enclosed, I could leave that open for heat to rise, but it would be up into the attic and out the ridge vents.

Any pros or cons? Am I off base?

Comment: The question is a bit broad for our format (we're a Q&A platform and not a discussion forum). If you're asking whether it's appropriate in your case, probably not. Most of the heat is accumulating through greenhouse effect--solar energy coming through the glass and being absorbed by surfaces inside. Ventilation or air conditioning are your best bets.

Comment: Also, "cold" isn't a thing. Insulation blocks heat transfer in one direction or another. You maybe understand this, but it's important when designing for energy efficiency.